# Angular2 formBuilder y Validators no validan en todos los casos

Tags: angularjs-2.0

Resulta que tengo un componente para dar de alta articulos en angular2. Cuando creo el componente vacío, las validaciones se realizan correctamente. Ahora bien, cuando al mismo componente lo utilizo para editar un articulo e inicializo el form con datos, este no se valida. Que puede estar pasando?.

Les pongo los sources...
article-form.component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { DropdownModule, ModalDirective } from 'ng2-bootstrap';
import { ToasterContainerComponent, ToasterService } from 'angular2-toaster';

import { WSRESTArticle } from '../../../../services/article.services';
import { ArticleVO } from  '../../../../services/ArticleVO';


@Component({
selector: 'article',
providers: [ToasterService],
template: require('./article-form.html'),
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class ArticleFormComponent implements OnInit {
@ViewChild('childModal') childModal: ModalDirective;
private toasterService: ToasterService;

public trxForm;

title : string;
caption: string;
add: boolean;
idarticle: number;

states = [{"id": 1, "state": 'Habilitado'}, {"id": 0, "state": 'Inhabilitado'}];

constructor(public fb: FormBuilder, 
            private router: Router,
            private route: ActivatedRoute, 
            protected serviceArticle: WSRESTArticle,
            toasterService: ToasterService) {

    console.log('Article-Form constructor');
    this.toasterService = toasterService;

    this.trxForm =this.fb.group({
      description:  ["", [Validators.required]],
      price:        ["", [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$')]],
      flagenabled:  ["", [Validators.required]]
    });
}

ngOnInit() {
    var id = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      var id = params['id'];

      this.title = id ? 'Editar Artículo' : 'Agregar Nuevo Artículo';
      this.caption = id ? 'Confirmar cambios' : 'Confirmar alta';
      this.add = id ? false : true;

      if (!id)
          return;

      this.idarticle = id;

      this.serviceArticle.Get(this.idarticle)
          .subscribe((data:ArticleVO) => this.fillArticleForm(data),
          error => console.log(error),
          () => console.log('Get article complete'));
    });
}

doCleanPrepare(): void {
  this.trxForm.reset();
}

goBack(): void {
  this.router.navigate(['pages/articles']);
}

doPost(): void {
    if (!this.idarticle)
    {
      this.serviceArticle
        .Add(this.trxForm.value.description, this.trxForm.value.price, this.trxForm.value.flagenabled.id)
        .subscribe((data:string) => {
          console.log(data);
          this.toasterService.pop('success', 'Agregar Artículo', 'Artículo insertado correctamente!.');
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
          this.toasterService.pop('error', 'Agregar Artículo', 'Error - El Artículo no puedo ser agregado!.');
        },
        () => console.log('insertar article finalizado'));
    }
    else {
      let article = new ArticleVO();
      article.description = this.trxForm.value.description;
      article.price = this.trxForm.value.price;
      article.flagenabled = this.trxForm.value.flagenabled.id;

      this.serviceArticle
        .Update(this.idarticle, article)
        .subscribe((data:ArticleVO) => {
          console.log(data);
          this.toasterService.pop('success', 'Editar Artículo', 'Artículo actualizado correctamente!.');
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
          this.toasterService.pop('error', 'Editar Artículo', 'Error - El Artículo no puedo ser actualizado!.');
        },
        () => console.log('actualizar article finalizado'));
    }
}

private fillArticleForm(data:ArticleVO): void {

    this.trxForm = this.fb.group({
      description: data.description,
      price: data.price,
      flagenabled: this.states.find(myobj => myobj.id == data.flagenabled)
    });
}
```

}

article-form.html

```
<div class="widgets">
<toaster-container></toaster-container>
  <div class="row">
    <button class="btn btn-success col-lg-1" (click)="goBack()">Regresar</button>
    <h3 class="col-lg-11">{{title}}</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<br>

<div class="row">
  <form [formGroup]="trxForm">
    <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error':!trxForm.controls['description'].valid && trxForm.controls['description'].touched}">
      <label for="description">Descripción</label>
      <input formControlName="description" type="text" class="form-control" id="description" placeholder="Descripción">
      <div *ngIf="!trxForm.controls['description'].valid && trxForm.controls['description'].touched">
        <p *ngIf="trxForm.controls['description'].hasError('required')" class="alert alert-danger">* El campo Descripción es obligatorio</p>
      </div>
    </div>

<div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error':!trxForm.controls['price'].valid && trxForm.controls['price'].touched}">
  <label for="price">Precio</label>
  <input formControlName="price" type="text" class="form-control" id="price" placeholder="Precio">
  <div *ngIf="!trxForm.controls['price'].valid && trxForm.controls['price'].touched">
    <p *ngIf="trxForm.controls['price'].hasError('required')" class="alert alert-danger">* El campo Precio es obligatorio</p>
    <p *ngIf="trxForm.controls['price'].hasError('pattern')" class="alert alert-danger">* El campo Precio debe ser numérico</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error':!trxForm.controls['flagenabled'].valid && trxForm.controls['flagenabled'].touched}">
  <label for="flagenabled">Habilitado</label>
  <select formControlName="flagenabled" name="flagenabled" class="form-control">
    <option [ngValue]="i" *ngFor="let i of states" >{{i.state}}</option>
  </select>
  <div *ngIf="!trxForm.controls['flagenabled'].valid && trxForm.controls['flagenabled'].touched">
    <p *ngIf="trxForm.controls['flagenabled'].hasError('required')" class="alert alert-danger">* El campo Habilitado es obligatorio</p>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-danger" [disabled]="!trxForm.valid" (click)="doPost()">{{caption}}</button>
<button class="btn btn-success" [hidden]="!add" (click)="doCleanPrepare()">Limpiar y Preparar Nuevo</button>

  </form>
</div>
<br>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

despues de un tiempo logré resolver este problema. El mismo estaba en el metodo FillArticleForm. No habia puesto los validadores (suponiendo que cuando lo declaré ya era suficiente)...es por ello que en el create funcionaba, pero en el edit, como los ponia, no lo hacia. Les dejo el método por si a alguno le sirve. Gracias!.

```
private fillArticleForm(data:ArticleVO): void {

        this.trxForm = this.fb.group({
          description:  [data.description, [Validators.required]],
          price:        [data.price, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$')]],
          flagenabled:  [this.states.find(myobj => myobj.id == data.flagenabled), [Validators.required]]
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Tiene que ver en cómo estás manejando el feedback o manejo de los errores, para hacer eso mismo que estás intentando hacer, yo hago:

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <!-- Name Field -->
    <label for="example-name" class="form-control-label">Nombre:</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" id="example-name" placeholder="Example" class="form-control" minlength="3" maxlength="24" name="name" [(ngModel)]="example.name" #name="ngModel" required>
    </div>
    <!-- Feedback name -->
    <div *ngIf="name.errors && name.touched" class="alert alert-danger">
      <div [hidden]="!name.errors.required">
        El nombre es obligatorio.
      </div>
      <div [hidden]="!name.errors.minlength">
        El nombre debe ser mayor o igual a 3 caracteres.
      </div>
      <div [hidden]="!name.errors.maxlength">
        El nombre debe ser menor a 25 caracteres.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```